# instantiate FileReader inside a loop without having error java heap space

Tags: java, document, filereader

i am trying to instanciate the FileReader giving it a String path to a file inside a while Loop 
the problem is that after 30 files, i am getting the error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

the path is dynamically given to the fileReaders inside the loop :

```
DocumentBuilder doc= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
while (Index < Events.size() ) {
  String FileName = getFileName(canal,Date,time);
  Doc =doc.parse(new File(Deposit+File.separator+FileName));
  FileReader fR = new FileReader(Deposit+File.separator+FileName);
  PlaylistString =FileCopyUtils.copyToString(fR);
  if(Doc!=null && PlaylistString.contains(some_text)){
  // Some treatment **********
  }

}
```

here the FileName changes for each iteration

i want to find a way to avoid having the out of memory error 
i tried fR.close() ans System.gc() but i still have the error 
does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is holding a reference to the FileReader objects or to another object. (BTW: You have to close the FileReader, look for [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for easier handling) Its not necessarily the case that the FileReader is the problem it could also be another object which is retained (referenced) inside your program.

Try to use a profiler like [VisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) (or YourKit, is not free) to determine memory leaks.

Comment: thank you for your answer, do i have to close the FileReader inside the while loop ? because i did it and i still have the error

Comment: If you no longer need the FileReader then you have to close it - as soon as possible but not sooner. As I said, the FileReader may not be the cause of your problem, it could be another object which is referenced and no longer needed, like listeners which are registered every time or something like that.

Comment: ok i added a file.delete() and fR.close() ( the file id the object inside the  Doc =doc.parse(new File(Deposit+File.separator+FileName)); ) and it seems to work fine

Comment: Hello again, i still have the error when i avoid deleting the file isn't there any other way of instantiating the file and the FileReader ? the fR.close() optimizes the code but at a certain extinct

Comment: OutOfMemory means that the heap is exaused even after e GC. That means you allocated to many objects. This can occour if you allocate to many objects or you do not free existing objects (e.g. a short term listener is registered on a long term object and never deregistered so the long term object keeps a ref to the listener) VisualVM can help you detecting such memory leaks.